# Cannot find packages related to JUnit when compiling test code

Tags: java, testing, junit

Trying to get JUnit working on my computer. I'm using windows but I have also installed git bash as well (don't know if that makes a difference).

Anyway I've followed this tutorial linked below:

https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_environment_setup.htm

I'm trying to set the environment variables manually on windows but the instructions above aren't working for me.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/2TphK.jpg

^Here is a photo of my user variables after making the changes in the tutorial. On the above tutorial it says to link the JDK to a variable called JAVA_HOME, and mine worked perfectly with Path as seen in the image but it did not work with JAVA_HOME.

I'm honestly so confused, lost and frustrated. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

1. Why does your classpath settings has so many semi-colons?
2. You haven't set `JAVA_HOME` yet. Usually it's necessary to set
   `JAVA_HOME`, as it's assumed by most Java libraries. You can set the
   Java path by `%JAVA_HOME%\bin`.
3. What is your commmand line to run Junit? Have you compiled
   successfully?

Answer (score 0):

JUnit has its own [Getting Started](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Getting-started). Can you try it instead of the tutorial that you used. It does not rely on environment variables. Therefore it should be easier to run it.